# 404 in accessing http://localhost:9090/swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a spring boot application and I want to generate swagger documentation for my APIs using springfox. Getting 404 undefined error while hitting http://localhost:9090/swagger-ui.html

Please find the stack trace below:

```
com.etc.common.services.interceptor.CommonServicesRequestInterceptor - Request URL - /swagger-resources/configuration/ui, Query String - null, HTTP Method - GET
com.etc.common.services.interceptor.CommonServicesRequestInterceptor - Request URL - /swagger-resources/configuration/ui, Response Status - 200
com.etc.common.services.interceptor.CommonServicesRequestInterceptor - Request URL - /swagger-resources/configuration/security, Query String - null, HTTP Method - GET
com.etc.common.services.interceptor.CommonServicesRequestInterceptor - Request URL - /swagger-resources/configuration/security, Response Status - 200
com.etc.common.services.interceptor.CommonServicesRequestInterceptor - Request URL - /swagger-resources, Query String - null, HTTP Method - GET
com.etc.common.services.interceptor.CommonServicesRequestInterceptor - Request URL - /swagger-resources, Response Status - 200
com.etc.common.services.interceptor.CommonServicesRequestInterceptor - Request URL - /error, Query String - null, HTTP Method - GET com.etc.common.services.interceptor.CommonServicesRequestInterceptor - Request URL - /error, Response Status - 404
```

Please find the screenshot for the same:
   [swagger-ui.html error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JULY.png)

Comment: you need to set view resolver

Comment: you need to set you view resolver in .property file